# Select All Checkboxes By Class in goup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

hello community I have a question, I am using `checkboxes` within an html table, with name `table1`, and I managed to select all the checkboxes by means of only one, but at the time of putting another table the same, with name `table2`, with their id of the different checkbox Table1, when I click on select all, it selects the checkboxes of the two tables as I do so that each table selects only its checkboxes?

I am using this code in jquery to select all checkboxes from table 1:

```
 $("#checkbox-bulk-select").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

and this from table 2:

```
 $("#checkbox-bulk-select2").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
```

> but it does not take the id, it selects all the checkboxes of both
> tables

these are the inputs to select all:

```
table1
<input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-bulk-select" type="checkbox">

table2
<input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-bulk-select2" type="checkbox">
```

[image]

Comment: because you access all inputs - `$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);` (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: This is your problem `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: You need to write something like that - `$('.table1 input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);`

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to replace ('input: checkbox') so that it works, please

Comment: #checkbox-bulk-select and  #checkbox-bulk-select2 They are the id of the checkboxes that select everything

Comment: Are `#checkbox-bulk-select` and `#checkbox-bulk-select2` inside or outside their concerned table?

Comment: I still do not put id to the tables only to the chekbox

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, I already made it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my example with your problem into `$('input:checkbox')`
Because, jquery file collides with the same code if you use `input:checkbox`
So using a `name="..."` with jquery code like `$('input:checkbox[name=table1]')`

**This snippet**

```js
$("#checkbox-bulk-select").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[name=table1]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    }); 

 $("#checkbox-bulk-select2").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox[name=table2]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
table1
    <input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-bulk-select" type="checkbox" name="table1">

table2

<input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-bulk-select2" type="checkbox" name="table2">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, it worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

From the current checkbox select the table that it is in and use that table to find all the checkboxes in it

```
$(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
```